# How to specify type of literal object and comply with TSLint?

Tags: typescript, casting, tslint, type-assertion

TSLint marks both of these as errors:
`const a = {} as MyClass; // no-object-literal-type-assertion`
`const a = <MyClass>{}; // no-angle-bracket-type-assertion`

And advices to use explicit typing:
`let a: MyClass`

But what should you use when just using literals and not assignments?
`return { name: 'john' } as MyClass`
`return <MyClass> { name: 'john' }`

What alternative can be used there without declaring a variable?

Comment: Annotate the function return type like `function foo(): MyClass { return {name: 'john'} }`?  But without a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE like [the TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wR5k1W) I can't test this suggestion. Could you provide a demonstrable self-contained code example?

Comment: Well, I'd had to create a project with TSLint and configure it, not worth it.
Anyway, your answer was actually pretty good.

Comment: You can at least give a definition of `MyClass` without needing to install TSLint, right?  I'm happy to make a self-serving guess (e.g., `interface MyClass {}`) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqEM2m), but then it would be unfortunate if some use case you care about is not supported.  Let me know.

Comment: I don't fully understand your last comment, but I'm thinking that the only places where I may need to create a `MyClass` literal are in an assignment and a function return. And both can be fixed by annotating either the l-value of the assignment or the function return type as you mentioned, so I think my use cases are already covered.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking for you to give a [mre] of at least the definition of `MyClass`, so that I can at least make sure that my suggestion would work for the relevant use cases.  If you don't want to do that (although it doesn't seem like much effort) then I will assume something minimal like `interface MyClass { }` and just hope for the best.

Comment: > return { name: 'john' } as MyClass

Specifically with this line, the "MyClass" should be specified as the function return type, not declared inline at return time.

yourFunction(input: string): MyClass{
   return { /* your MyClass object */ };
}

Comment: @jcalz oh, it's not about the effort, MyClass is just a class that's defined on my project, it's not relevant what its definition is, but it's ok anyways as the only places I though I needed to do a type assertion were on assignment and function return, and you already gave good examples of how to type annotate both the assignment and the function return type, so it's solved.

Comment: Maybe we're talking past each other? When you provide a code example in a Stack Overflow question, it is recommended, fairly strongly, for you to make it a [mre]. I'm sure you are aware of this, so I apologize for belaboring the point. The example code in this question is not, because it references an undeclared `MyClass` type. The goal here is not only to help the person asking the question, but so the question and answer pair can serve as a good FAQ entry for future readers. I'm not sure what our disconnect is, but since you've apparently already accepted another answer, I will disengage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place explicit interface definitions inline. Starting with the example:

```
interface IGuy {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
const guy: IGuy = {name: 'N', age: 1 };
```

With a slight alteration to the format, we can place that same interface inline, explicitly and anonymously:

```
const guy: { name: string, age: number } = {name: 'N', age: 1 };
```

It also works in function signatures:

```
myFunction(guy: { name: string, age: number)) { //
```

This pairs well with object destructuring:

```
myFunction({ name, age }: { name: string, age: number) { //
```

If your output return value matches the function return signature, you should be OK, if this is OK to you:

```
function myFunction(): { name: string, age: number} {
  return { name: 'N', age: 1 };
}
```

Comment: Yes, totally ok, thanks!